# how to make currency format thousand seperator with comma or dot with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, decimal, currency

I would like to print this script currency format thousand separator with comma or dot with javascript.

I mean ,for example  I would print 1.001,00 instead of 1001

which code should I add for this script ?

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('input').change(function(){
    var linetotals = 0;
    $('[name^="price"]').each(function(){
        price = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(0).val();
        quantity = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(1).val();
        $(this).val(price*quantity);
        linetotals += price*quantity;
    });
    $('[name=subtotal]').val(linetotals);
});
});

    </script>
```

```
   <form name="invoice form" action="saveToDatabase.java">
    <table width="30%" border="1" height="30%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="center">Customer Invoice</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="5%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Sn.no.</td>
                <td width="25%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Item</td>
                <td width="25%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Unit Price(In $)</td>
                <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Quantity</td>
                <td width="25%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Line Total<br>(Price * Qnty)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="5%">1</td>
                <td width="25%">Iphone 5S</td>
                <td width="25%"><input value="400" name="unitprice1" size="4" type="text"></td>
                <td width="20%"><input name="quantity1" value="2" size="2" type="text"></td>
                <td width="25%"><input name="price1" value="400" size="4" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="5%">2</td>
                <td width="25%">Ipad 2</td>
                <td width="25%"><input value="700" name="unitprice2" size="4" disabled="" type="text"></td>
                <td width="20%"><input name="quantity2" value="1" size="2" type="text"></td>
                <td width="25%"><input name="price2=" value="700" size="4" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="5%">1</td>
                <td width="25%">mp3</td>
                <td width="25%"><input value="50" name="unitprice1" size="4" disabled="" type="text"></td>
                <td width="20%"><input name="quantity1" value="3" size="2" type="text"></td>
                <td width="25%"><input name="price1" value="150" size="4" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="right">Total<input name="subtotal" value="1250" size="12" disabled="" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/LGyeq/)

Comment: Are you trying to do it yourself as an exercise? Or are you open to using existing libraries?

Comment: I would advise you to have a look at [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Using_locales) You may do like `(1000000).toLocaleString('de-DE');`